# mysql is not installing by python-pip using terminal in Linux

Tags: python-3.x

> I want to install mysql using my python-pip....but every time i try to install it, it shows me
>   an error*I tried every single technique..but this error is showing on linux terminal*
>
> Command

```
pip install mysql
```

> Error

```
    Complete output (31 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-b05tg0vo/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-b05tg0vo/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-2b0kpfjn/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Looks like you need some system libraries because it is trying to build native portions of the code. Have you installed the required system libs?

Comment: Please tell me how to install these system libs?

Comment: You should add your operating system as a tag. Also, you shouldn't be using pip to install packages system wide. Use your package manager, create a virtual environment, or at least use `pip install --user mysql`

Comment: Virtual environment for python?? in my project file or overall?

Comment: Python has a module 'virtual environment' which lets you make a python environment, so you don't ruin your system python. eg. `python3 -m venv mysql-test-env` will create a folder with a python virtual environment in it. Then `mysql-test-env/bin/pip install mysql` will install mysql into that environment without modifying your system at all.